# TortoiseGitで赤いビックリマークが消えない

Tags: tortoisegit

TortoiseGitで赤いビックリマークが消えません。
コミットをしようとしても「最後のコミットから変更/追加されたファイルはありません。」と表示されます。
赤いビックリマークが付いているディレクトリを見ても何も入っていません。
この状態になってから一回コミットしてみましたがやはり消えません。
フォルダの強制リロード、pcの再起動をやってもだめです。

原因として思い当たるのは、ちょっと前にファイルをgitでなく普通に削除して、コミットするときに「行方不明」を「削除」に状態変更してコミットしたことです。
まさに削除したファイルの入っていたディレクトリまで赤いビックリマークが付いています。

赤いビックリマークから緑のチェックマークに戻す方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: コマンドでgit status もしくはメニューの「Check for modifications」で確認すると何が表示されますか？

Comment: 日本語メニューで言うところの「変更をチェック(F)」で良いでしょうか。それで確認したところ「現在の設定では表示するファイルはありません。バージョン管理外、無視、未変更、のファイルを見るためには以下の設定にチェックをしてください。」と表示されます。リスト部分にはこれ以外表示されていません。更新しても変化はありません。

Comment: 助言を頂いていくつか確認する内にふっと思いついて解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もしやと思い、赤いビックリマークが残っているディレクトリに入っていたファイル(質問で明記した普通に削除してコミット時に削除状態にしたもの)をゴミ箱から一旦戻したら緑のチェックマークになりました。その後すぐディレクトリからまた取り出して削除してもちゃんと緑のチェックマークのままで問題無いようです。